# Is it possible to have two separate shells in python that are running the same script?

Tags: python, shell, tkinter

Essentially what I am looking for is a way to have two shells interacting with one script of the main program (Change variables and all that) and have the other shell see those changes.
for example:

shell 1 gets asked with teh input what it would like to add to the list, and types in "apple"

shell 2 who is also running the same script would be able to enter view and see that shell 1 had entered apple to List[1].

```
List = ["Oranges"]
UserInput = input("enter another fruit or 'V' for view")
if UserInput == "V":
    print(List)
else:
    List.append(UserInput)
```

shell 1 gets asked with the input what it would like to add to the list, and types in "Apples"
would see:
"enter another fruit or 'V' for view">"Apples"

shell 2 who is also running the same script would be able to enter view and see that shell 1 had entered apple to List.
would see:
enter another fruit or 'V' for view">"V"
[Oranges, Apples]

for my purposes the data would not have any collisions/errors with overwrite as two people would not be able to edit the same thing
not sure if what i have said makes sense but i have tried previously using TKinter as a pop out shell but did not end up working.

Comment: Have you looked at multithreading in python? What are some reasons for why this won't work for your particular situation?

Comment: Why do you need 2 shells. Usually different processes don't need to share data. Are the shells on different computers? How much data do you need to transmit? Have you looked at `multiprocessing`/`threading`/`os.pipe`/simple file read/writes?

Comment: I need two shells in order to simulate one program being used by two diffrent computers without any server set up stuff and only on one computer. I haven't looked into multiprocessing, treading and os.pipe but I will now. ill add a rely if any of those solutions work @TheLizzard

Comment: Please define what you mean by _shell_ in this context. If you have several processes, than by design you can't have "common variables". Perhaps it makes sense to look into [_shared memoy_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html), provided that the data to be shared can be seen as just a sequence of bytes.

Comment: I dont think I explained myself correctly: what I currently have is a mock HMS system. I need to have at least two shells in order to show it would be able to accessed by two diffrent doctors and theoretically more. these docs would be assigned patients that they could then edit the attributes off as they are stored as objects. but i would need to show that more than one doctor could edit patient attributes simultaneously within my system.

Comment: I left an answer that should help you to get started. If you're able to add more code and showcase how your current setup is working, I can edit my answer and maybe provide more concrete methods on how this could be potentially solved.

Comment: Whatever an HMS (Hospital Management System?) is, it probably won't be storing all of its data in memory. Why don't you use a database and show that instead? Sqlite is quite simple to get started with in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you will need to go to the extreme with testing via separate shells. Understandably you want to make sure that when data is accessed that you don't fall into any locking problems. A quick google search will yield many examples of how to do MultiThreading, here's the first result I found: [geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-python-set-1](https://geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-python-set-1) try this and learn a little about how this works.

Additionally, I would also recommend looking up testing [realpython.com/python-testing](https://realpython.com/python-testing) and how to do this, because you should be able to test your precise situation without having to create two shell windows.